# Detect whether there is a button in Canvas when user taps on screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am building an AR application that spawns a 3d model when user taps the screen on to the ground plane.

But the issue I am facing is that, I have placed a button at the bottom of the screen to take a screenshot. On clicking the button,it does take screenshots,but it spawns an image below the button also.

How can I avoid this ? Can I use raycast to detect a button,and not spawn the object there ?

Below is the code I use to place objects

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.Experimental.XR;
using System;

public class ArTapToPlace : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objectToPlace;
    public GameObject placementIndicator;

    private ARSessionOrigin arOrigin;
    private Pose placementPose;
    private bool placementPoseIsValid = false;

    void Start()
    {
        arOrigin = FindObjectOfType<ARSessionOrigin>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        UpdatePlacementPose();
        UpdatePlacementIndicator();

        if (placementPoseIsValid && Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            PlaceObject();
        }
    }

    private void PlaceObject()
    {
        Instantiate(objectToPlace, placementPose.position, placementPose.rotation);
    }

    private void UpdatePlacementIndicator()
    {
        print(placementIndicator);
        if (placementPoseIsValid)
        {
            placementIndicator.SetActive(true);
            placementIndicator.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(placementPose.position, placementPose.rotation);
        }
        else
        {
            placementIndicator.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    private void UpdatePlacementPose()
    {
        var screenCenter = Camera.current.ViewportToScreenPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f));
        var hits = new List<ARRaycastHit>();
        arOrigin.GetComponent<ARRaycastManager>().Raycast(screenCenter, hits, UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.TrackableType.Planes);
        print(hits.Count);
        print(hits);


        placementPoseIsValid = hits.Count > 0;
        if (placementPoseIsValid)
        {
            placementPose = hits[0].pose;

            var cameraForward = Camera.current.transform.forward;
            var cameraBearing = new Vector3(cameraForward.x, 0, cameraForward.z).normalized;
            placementPose.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(cameraBearing);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you detect the click on the plane?

Comment: arOrigin.GetComponent<ARRaycastManager>().Raycast(screenCenter, hits, UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.TrackableType.Planes);

Comment: I have added my code I use to place objects on to the ground plane @derHugo

Comment: yeahs I can see you only collect the `UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.TrackableType.Planes` so doing this you will never know whether you hit **only** the plane or something else before. I don't know that type but maybe you can either limit it to exactly one hit and check if it is a plane or a button, or rather use the normal [`Physics.RaycastAll`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html) and only to the positioning if the plane is the **only** thing hit

Comment: Otherwise maybe also [`EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject.html) could help here, depends how UI is implemented in your project

Comment: that worked(eventsystem). Thank you :) 

if you put that as an answer I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your UI is setup you can probably use [`EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.EventSystem.IsPointerOverGameObject.html) for checking if the pointer is over a UI element and skip the placing in this case

```
if (placementPoseIsValid && Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
{
    if(EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId))) return;

    PlaceObject();
}
```